# Confusion over modulus arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given: $x\equiv19\ (\textrm{mod}\ 5)$.

Identify which one of the following options gives integers that are valid solutions for $x$ ?

$-19$ and $7$,

$-11$ and $54$,

$7$ and $26$,

$11$ and $26$.

I then tried to emulate that process as follows.

$54 = 10\cdot 5$ with $r=4$

$54\equiv4\ (\textrm{mod}\ 5)$

$7=1\cdot 5 +2$

$2\ (\textrm{mod}\ 5)$

$11 = 2\cdot 5+1$

$1\ (\textrm{mod}\ 5)$

Basically I thought $x= Remainder\ (\textrm{mod}\ 5)$

Comment: 19 isn't currently in the form of a remainder $\mod 5$ - so work out $19\mod 5$, then compare this answer to remainders for the pairs of numbers you have given.

Comment: 19/5 Quotient of 3.... Remainder of 4.

Therefore, 

19mod 5=4 (?)

Answer (score 0):

$x\equiv y\mod n\iff x-y=kn$ for some integer $k$, so for example,
$$54-19=35=5k,$$ where $k=7$.

Answer (score -1):

What you show so far is correct:

$54\equiv 4\pmod 5\\7\equiv 2\pmod 5 \\11\equiv 1\pmod 5$

Perhaps what is more important, is that this equivalence is transitive.
$a\equiv x \pmod 5$ and $b \equiv x \pmod 5 \implies a\equiv b \pmod 5$

or $54\equiv 49\equiv 44\pmod 5$

So what is equivalent to 19?

Comment: I have went for Option B.

-11 and 54.

19/5 = Quotient of 3 and Remainder of 4.

Therefore 19 mod 5 =4

54/5 = Quotient of 10 and Remainder of 4

Therefore 54 mod 5 =4

finally

-11 = -3 x 5 +4 

Therefore 

-11 mod 5 =4

?

(I wanted to show my working, and also explain my working/methodology, because I want to be confident I have actually cracked the process rather than achieved a result from some fluke).

Comment: indeed $-11 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ that is perhaps slightly tricky.  But if you think about it that all number whose difference is divisible by 5 are equivalent, it might be an easier concept than actually calculating remainders.

Comment: I always find if I have a negative to just add a large multiple of $5$ to make it positive.  $-11 \equiv -11 + 15 = 4 \mod 5$.  Or alternatively get it dow to a "small negative" and then add $5$.  $-11 \equiv -1 \mod 5$.  And $-1 \equiv -1 + 5 = 4 \mod 5$.

Answer (score -1):

$x \equiv 19 \mod 5$ means $x$ will have the same remainder that $19$ will have.  It doesnt mean that $x$ will have $19$ as a remainder.  And $19\equiv 4 \mod 5$ so a $x$ will have remainder $4$.

!!BUT!! we aren't babies anymore.  Theres nothing magic about the one and only super secret *THE* remainder.  No-one gives a flying crap what the remainder of something is.  There's nothing *magical* about the remainder $4$ that that, $9$ or $14$ or $-1$ or $-6$ wouldn't do just as well.

What's ***REALLY*** important is that $x \equiv 19 \mod 5$ is that $x$ and $19$ are equivalent values some multiple of $5$ apart.  $x = 19 + 5k$ for some integer (positive, negative, or zero).

And we don't care what $k$ is either.  We are interested in the *relation* $x$ and $19$ have with each other in that  some multiple of $5$ apart.

So

....

$x \equiv 19\mod 5$.  That means if we subtract a bunch of $5$s we'll, get $x \equiv 4 \mod 5$.

$-19$. if we add a bunch of $5$ s we'll get $-19\equiv 1 \mod 5$ and $1 \not \equiv 4 \mod 5$ so $-19 \not \equiv 19 \mod 5$.  That's out.

$7$.  If we subtract a bunch of $5$ we'll get $7\equiv 2\not equiv 4 \mod 5$ so $7 \not \equiv 19 \mod 5$.

Now,.... here's a tip.  If $a \equiv b \mod 5$ that means we can add or subtract a $5$ to get from one to the other.  That means they are different by a multiple of $5$.  So if we subtract them $a -b$ that will be $a - b = 5k$ for some integer $k$.  And if we add or subtract a bunch of $5$ fro $a-b$ we'll get $0$.

So $a \equiv b \mod 5$ if and only if $a-b \equiv 0 \mod 5$.

$-11$.  $-11 - 19 = -30$ and $-30 = 0 \mod 5$.  $-11 \equiv 19 \mod 5$.  If we add a bunch of $5$s to $-11$ we will get $-11 + 15 = 4$ and $4 + 15 = 19$.  So $-11 \equiv 19 \mod 5$.

$54$.  Well we can see $54 \equiv 4 \mod 5$ and $19\equiv 4 \mod 5$ so $54\equiv 19 \mod 5$.  We can verify this be seed $19 + 35 = 54$ or that $54 - 19 = 35 \equiv 0 \mod 5$.

$-11$ and $54$ is a pair of solutions.